# Executing Batch File From C++ with Spaces in the Path

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd

I want to execute a batch file using `system()` and the path to the file will be passed to the function so it will look like this:

```
void executeBatch(char* BatchFile){
    system(BatchFile);
}
```

Now the issue is that the path passed in will not have the escape quotes to ignore spaces for example the user would input:

```
"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat"
```

How do I add escape quotes to the path passed in?

So I essentually change:

```
"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat"
```

to

```
"\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\""
```

Comment: go to this directory and make sure your file exists `C:\Users\500543\Documents\Batch File Project\Testing.bat`

Comment: @Nick As far as I understand, the OP will run into the same troubles, when trying to change the working directory, or not?

Comment: @g-makulik I am not asking to change working directory. I am asking to make sure the .bat file exists where he thinks it is sitting.

Comment: @Nick Wouldn't make any difference ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
system("\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\"");
```

As for your additional question from your comment, you have to use:

```
char* it = "\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\"";

system(it);
```

then.

As for your edited question, since you've marked the question to use [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), here's a c++ solution how to implement your function correctly:

```
#include <sstream>

int executeBatch(const char* fullBatchFileName)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << '\"' << fullBatchFileName << '\"';
    return system(oss.str().c_str());
}
```

**Don't make this an XY problem now!** I think you should have understood the principle from these samples: Just wrap your batch file name within a pair of double-quote characters (`'\"'`), that the shell can interpret it correctly.
There are also pure c library methods available to achieve this (see `<cstring>`) but I wouldn't recommend these, if you can use the c++ standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding escaped double-quotes around your command line, i.e.

```
system("\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes:

```
     system("\"C:\\Users\\500543\\Documents\\Batch File Project\\Testing.bat\"");
```